# Add user role based on Profile2 Field Using Rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

What I am trying to achieve is:
1) I have a Profile2 field in the user registration form called: "Firm Type"
2) I need to assign the new user a Role based on the selection in this field.

I have tried the following:

**Event:** After saving a new account
**Condition:** Data Comparison: account:profile-additional-registration-info:field-profile-firm-type
**Action:** Add a user role

The above Rule works fine when I remove the condition. As soon as I add the condition the rule does not work.
**Digging into this I found out that Rule gets executed after Account is saved and before  Profile2 is saved.**

I looked online to find these 2 links helpful:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1872384
https://www.drupal.org/node/2009878

1 suggestion was:
**Event:** After saving a new profile
**Condition:** Data Comparison: Profile2:field
**Action: Heres where the problem is -- I cannot get to the account level because its on a profile event.**

Could you please help me figure this out. Any help would be really appreaciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. I just figured it out. Incase if this helps anyone, here are the steps:

Event:
After adding a new profile
After updating an existing profile

Condition:
Negate User Has Roles: Check all roles other than a Public Role
<This is will not update the role if user is already in the system with another role and updates his profile>
Data Comparison: profile2:field

Action:
Set a Data Value: site:current-user:roles
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

- Rules **Event**: After adding a new profile After updating an existing profile
- Rules **Condition**: Negate User Has Roles: Check all roles other than a Public Role  Data Comparison: profile2:field
- Rules **Action**: Set a Data Value: `site:current-user:roles`